# KolourPaint increase brush size

Tags: image-processing, kde-apps, kolourpaint

is there a way to increase the size of the pen tool in kolourpaint? mspaint had <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> make the pen draw thicker lines.

Also, is it possible to assign "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>" as a shortcut for increasing brush size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pen tool is set to use the smallest brush square head.

As for increasing the brush size and shape, there is a submenu that appears below the dialogue tool set when clicked.

Essentially the brush small square head is the same as the pen.

While we are at it, Libre Draw is a far superior product and very intuitive friendly.

Comment: how did I not notice that! thanks XD ...libreoffice draw's nice but it's style is a bit different than that casual "paint program" style (if you know what I mean), thanks anyway :D